# php oop Call to private method

Tags: php, oop

I have a class that look like this

```
class a {

    private $one;

    private function abc() {

    $this->one = "I am a string";
    return $this;
}

$call = new a;
$call->abc()->other_function();
```

As I was doing matutor method, php has caught a fatal error on calling function abc(). It said Call to private method xxx from context.

What I know of oop is very new, that private method/property can only be used within the same class.However, I cannot call the abc() even it is within the same class.

How come?

Comment: You can call it from *within* the class. Not outside of it. To call it outside of the class it must be public.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Dont know why I get -1 for being a bit ignorant....I tried to look for an answer, but cant find it stated clearly on this.....

@AndreiP. if I have multiple property to return, how will I do this? Thanks :)

Comment: Encapsulate the properties to return into an `array`, and return that array, but this is already another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not calling the method **inside** the class you are doing so outside the class code.

```
$call = new a;
$call->abc()->other_function();
```

this is outside the context of the class, and this is why you get a Fatal Error.

Answer (score 0):

`Private` can only be used in the class itself.

`Protected` can only be used in the class itself and child classes.

`Public` can be used anywhere.

```
class a {

    private $one;

    public function abc() { //notice the public

      $this->one = "I am a string";
      return $this->one; 
    }
}

$call = new a;
echo $call->abc();
```